# Magento 2 - Invalid Samesite attribute error on reindex command

Tags: reindex

I am getting "**Invalid Samesite attribute**." error while run the `reindex` command from CLI

"`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`" in the magento 2 setup (version 2.4.4, PHP 8.1, and Apache).

I have tried all the way to find out the solution but no luck.

Can someone please help with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.. Actually the "CookieSameSite" variable was set to "None" in the code and its fixed by setting "Lax". Now the reindex is working fine.